# How to move existing files into new packages?

Tags: java, package

I have a recent Java project in Eclipse that I would now like to separate into different packages. To be more precise, I want to create the packages "assign1.model", "assign1.controller" and "assign1.view". Then, I want to sort my different .java files into these packages.¨

I have just done this. So now my view for example has this in the beginning:

```
package assign1.view;
import assign1.controller.*;
import assign1.model.*;
```

The problem is, when I now try to start my main program (the view) I get this error:

```
"Could not find or load main class assign1.view.Desktop" (Desktop is the name of my view class).
```

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

When you change a class's package ... you also need to:

a) move the .java source file into the corresponding directory (package path == directory tree),

b) change all "imports" in all .java source that references the old path, and

c) recompile all.

If you're using an IDE (e.g. Eclipse), a "refactor" will do most of this automagically for you.